# Proof of :$H^0(E;\pi_0E)\cong \hom_{\pi_0}(H_0(E;E_0);\pi_0E)$ for $E$ a multiplicative spectrum.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, spectra

Let $E$ be a multiplicative spectrum, connective, and assume $\pi_0E$ is cyclic.

I want to prove that $$H^0(E;\pi_0E)\cong \hom_{\pi_0E}(H_0(E;\pi_0E);\pi_0E)$$

Recall that $H^0(E;\pi_0E):= [E; K(\pi_0E)]$ and $H_0(E;\pi_0E):=\pi_0(E \wedge K(\pi_0E))$.

**My attempt:** It's equivalent to prove that the pairing $$\langle H^0(E;\pi_0E) , H_0(E;\pi_0E) \rangle \to  \pi_0E$$ is perfect. But I don't know how to proceed with computation since I don't know much about the cohomology $H^0(E;\pi_0E)$, nor the maps $[E; K(\pi_0E)]$.

Can someone give me some hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the Hurewicz theorem for spectra, if $X$ is a connective spectrum, then $H_n(X;\mathbb{Z})=0$ for $n<0$ and $H_0(X;\mathbb{Z})\cong \pi_0(X)$.  It follows by the universal coefficient theorems that for any abelian group $A$, $H_0(X;A)\cong \pi_0(X)\otimes A$ and $H^0(X;A)\cong \operatorname{Hom}(\pi_0(X),A)$.

Applying this with $X=E$ and $A=\pi_0(E)$, it is then trivial to see that if $\pi_0(E)$ is cyclic, the two groups you are comparing are both isomorphic to $\pi_0(E)$.

Comment: Dear Eric, thanks for your answer. There are two things unclear to me: 1) do we have a UCT even for (co)homology of spectra? 2) I don't get the second half of your answer. if we have $H^0(X;A)\cong \hom (\pi_0X,A)$ then I'm done right? Why do I need the last two passages? in other words, where do we use the fact that $\pi_0(X)$ is cyclic?

Comment: 1) Yes.  For instance, you can define a cellular (co)chain complex for CW spectra, and then prove much as in the case of spaces that cellular (co)homology coincides with (co)homology defined in terms of Eilenberg-MacLane spaces.  The UCT for cellular (co)homology is then just pure homological algebra.  2) You're right, that's not necessary.  I was just being lazy.